# Importing Excel data into SQL table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Trying to import Excel data into SQL table using SSIS.

```
1. One of the column values in excel has combination of intergers & decimals
2. Sql table has column with data type `nvarchar(100)` 
3. After the import I got Null values in that field.
```

then I changed the data type to Float and now i get an error.

What's the right data type?

Here are the sample values, i'm going to have in excel

```
ColumnA
100
200
0.0342
103
0.45909090
```

Also I need to restrict the decimal values to 5 digits after decimal without rounding off just truncating. For instance 0.45909090 would be 0.45909

What's the correct data type for the column(in SQL table).

Comment: you can try the `real` datatype, and if you use a derived column transformation you can round your decimals off

Comment: Here is the error i get if i use anything other than nvarchar "[OLE DB Destination [14]] Error: There was an error with input column "Metric field value " (215) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (27). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
I have not used derived column transformation.

Comment: Check what the data type is coming from the excel file. Check the excel connection manager data type for that column. Check the data type for your oledb connection manager. Finally, check the column in the database you're trying to put stuff in. These must all be the same type. If you want to cast your data to any other type you can use the derived column transform. If you want to convert your data to any other type use the data conversion tool.

Comment: Datatype coming from excel & connection manager is all Unicode DT_WSTR. Datatype on oledb connection manager is nvarchar(255). Thought nvarchar is equivalent to Unicode DT_WSTR. Also with nvarchar i dont get any error but column value doesn't show up either.

Comment: No matter what casts & conversions i use it doesn't work!

Comment: I realized there are Null in the field/column. Here is what the sample data looks like                                        ColumnA
100
200
Null 
0.0342
103
0.45909090 However when i use DT_WSTR or DT_STR, all real values are ignored and field is populated with Null from top to bottom. Again if i use any other data type other DT_WSTR or DT_STR with data conversion tranformation or derived column tranformation. package gives an error. I'm not sure if it doesn't know how to handle mixed data or null in the source.

Comment: Did figure out the issue. thx for the help but it's outside of what TsSKTO provided

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. You won't get the bounty, but it might help others.